# Module comctl32.ocx failed to load in Windows 10 Home

Tags: vb.net, regsvr32

I have an old VB 6 app that someone is trying to install.  The user is trying to register Comctl32.ocx.  The file is in C:\windows\system32.  The user has Windows 10 Home.  When trying to register using:

```
Regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\comctl32.ocx
```

The user gets the message:

> The module "comctl32.ocx" failed to load.  Make sure the binary is
>   stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with
>   the binary or dependent .DLL files.  The specified module could not be
>   found.

Any ideas what the user can try?

Comment: Is he running as admin  ?

Comment: yes he is running as an admin

Answer (score 2):

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873

Basically: You are trying to register from the wrong directory, 32 bit OCx must be in c:\windows\syswow64

Also make sure you execute that command from an elevated command prompt (Admin).